# How get text from button clicked in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a button in storyboard, i wanna when clicked on button get text from sender @IBaction, sample code in below

```swift
@IBAction func click(_ sender: UIButton) {
  print(sender.titleLabel?.text)
  print(sender.currentTitle)
}
```

Now my problem is that when I get the button text from `sender.titleLabel?.text` it returns the value of `optional(button text)` and when i try get button text from `sender.currentTitle` it return the `nil`.

Comment: If you added a default `UIButton` in Storyboard, and set its title there, `sender.currentTitle` should **not** be `nil`. Are you doing something to the title via code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sender.titleLabel?.text` is returning an [`Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) because `titleLabel` might be `nil`.

You need to [unwrap the Optional](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/10/2/unwrapping-optionals).

Comment: Thank’s a lot this correct, do you know why ```sender.curentTitle```  return  ```nil``` ?